# Fermi-Dirac distribution at $T=0$

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-statistics

**Problem 7.33-b)** *(Daniel.V.Schroeder-An introduction to thermal physics)*:

> When attractive forces of the ions in a crystal are taken into
>   account, then the allowed energies are grouped into bands, separated
>   by gaps where there are no allowed energies. In a conductor the Fermi
>   energy lies within one of the bands; in this section we have treated
>   the electrons in this band as "free" particles confined to a fixed
>   volume. In an insulator the Fermi energy lies within a gap, so that at
>   $T=0$ the band below the gap is completely occupied and the band above
>   the gap is unoccupied. A semiconductor is an insulator in which the
>   gap is narrow enough for a few electrons to jump across it at room
>   temperature. Figure below shows the density of states in the vicinity
>   of the Fermi energy for an idealized semiconductor, and defines some
>   terminology and notation to be used in this problem.
>
> b) Normally the width of the gap is much greater than $kT$. Also, let $g(\epsilon)=g_0\sqrt{\epsilon-\epsilon_c},$ where $g_0$ is a constant independent of $\epsilon.$ Working in
>   this limit, derive an expression for the number of conduction
>   electrons per unit volume, in terms of temperature and the width of
>   the gap.

[image]

I found a solution online which calculates the number of conduction electrons using

$$N_c=\int_\limits{\epsilon_c}^{\infty}g(\epsilon)\bar{n}_{FD}(\epsilon) \ d\epsilon=g_0\int_\limits{\epsilon_c}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon-\epsilon_c}}{\exp((\epsilon-\epsilon_F)/kT)+1} \ d\epsilon. \tag1$$

What I don't understand here is that in the same book they state that for $T=0$ we have $\mu=\epsilon_F$ and the formula for the number of electrons is given simply by

$$N=\int_\limits{0}^{\infty}g(\epsilon) \ d\epsilon.\tag2$$

So why doesn't $(2)$ apply to the problem at hand?

The correct answer seems to be

$$\frac{N_c}{V}=\left(\frac{2\pi m k T}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}2e^{-2(\epsilon-\epsilon_F)/kT}.$$

Using the theory about the limit of the Fermi-Dirac distribution in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509513/fermi-dirac-distribution-at-t-0?noredirect=1#comment1148065_509513) thread then I should get

$$N_c=\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}g_0\int_\limits{\epsilon_c}^{\infty}\sqrt{\epsilon-\epsilon_c}\cdot\frac{1}{\exp((\epsilon-\epsilon_F)/kT)+1} \ d\epsilon = g_0\int_{\epsilon_c}^{\infty}\sqrt{\epsilon-\epsilon_c} \ d\epsilon = \infty.$$

Thus the theory in that thread does not help here at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions about the Fermi-Dirac distribution at $T=0.$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509434/questions-about-the-fermi-dirac-distribution-at-t-0)  Please stop asking the same question again and again.

Comment: It's not at all the same question. In this one, I'm wondering why the formula I have learned does not apply to the given problem, whereas in the other question I'm asking something else related to the distribution at $T=0.$ Read my questions before you burden yourself by typing something, and also wasting my time explaining it in the comment.

Comment: If this is a question about $T>0$, why use the same title as before? Or this is in fact the same conceptual hurdle as before. You did not understand the answers given there, and are burdening us with a new thread.

Comment: I've added an edit now. Hope it explains my question better. I'm not sure how to vary the title to be more specific.

Comment: Thats my question exactly, is it $T=0$ or $T>0$? They seem to mix both of them! First they clearly assume $T=0$ when setting up the integral (distribution $\neq$1) and then they use $\mu = \epsilon_F$ which is only valid at $T=0$. Do you see my confusion now?